# How to resolve in snakemake error : "Target rules may not contain wildcards."

Tags: snakemake

I would like to do easily reproducible analysis using publicly available data from NCBI, so I have chosen a `snakemake`.

I would like to write a single rule, that would be able to download any genome given a species code name and separated table of species and their NCBI IDs. So I wrote a script `scripts/download.sh` that takes a species code and download the genome to `data/<species_code>/genome.fa.gz`. The script internally reads the table `tables/download_table.tsv`, where are corresponding species code names and NCBI IDs.

So I tried to do a `snakemake` like this :

```
species='Cbir Avag Fcan Lcla Dcor Dpac Pdav Psp62 Psp79 Minc1 Minc2 Mjav Mare Mflo Mhap Pant'

rule download:
    input :
        "tables/download_table.tsv"
    output :
        "data/{sp}/genome.fa.gz"
    shell :
        "scripts/download.sh {sp}"
```

However, `snakemake` returned an error message I do not really understand :

```
Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.`.
```

Is there a way to write a single rule for downloading all the genomes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you need a master rule that requires all of your desired outputs as inputs, in your case it would be :

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/{sp}/genome.fa.gz", sp=species.split(' '))
```

You'll also need separate download link inputs for each species. You could make a separate `download_table.tsv` for each species, but it would probably be easier to make a config file with this information, and add a params keyword to your rule. Something like:

```
rule download:
   params:
       url=config['locations']['sp']
   output :
       "data/{sp}/genome.fa.gz"
   shell :
       "scripts/download.sh {params.url}"
```

Comment: I wouldn't erase it if I were you. A lot of people get confused about Snakemake error messages, so its helpful to have some examples on here.

Comment: Then I will at least dramatically edit it. (I try to do it in a way so your answer still fits)

Comment: @KamilSJaron I agree the question should be kept, but maybe change the title to reflect the error message, this has nothing to do with NCBI

Comment: Also note that Snakemake has an NCBI remote provider: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#genbank-ncbi-entrez

Comment: @JohannesKöster I was looking at it. But since I could not make it work without remote I have not even tried with remote. And then the problem I originally had with non-remote solution is very much unrelated to downloading of sequences. It's a good tip though, maybe work an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Given the Makefile you provided and which someone then deleted from the question, you should probably just add this line (this should be the first rule):

`rule all: input: ["data/{}/genome.fa.gz".format(x) for x in species.split()]`

This rule just specifies a list of expected output files and corresponds to the following lines from the original `Makefile`:

`GENOMES=$(patsubst %, data/%/genome.fa.gz, $(SPECIES))
all : $(GENOMES)`

Comment: I have deleted Make equivalent since was not really related to the problem.